# RFID connect! works fine but causing to open multi forms

Tags: c#, rfid

I have coded the software, it works fine and RFID device works as well in login box, as soon person login using RFID device key, it goes to main page however RFID connection still open and donot close and when someone put other key near RFID device, one more windows open and auto login with other login id, how to stop it ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
//using System.Diagnostics;
//using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using Phidgets;
using Phidgets.Events;

namespace GYM_Management
{
  public partial class Login : GYM_Management.Form1
  {

    RFID   rfid1;
    string lastRFIDTag;
    Int32  TagCtr;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lastRFIDTag = "";
        TagCtr = 0;
    }
    connection cc = new connection();
    SpeechSynthesizer sp = new SpeechSynthesizer();


    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Enabled = true;
        rfid1 = new RFID();
        rfid1.Attach += new AttachEventHandler(rfid_Attach);
        rfid1.Detach += new DetachEventHandler(rfid_Detach);
        rfid1.RFIDTag += new TagEventHandler(rfid_Tag);
        rfid1.RFIDTagLost += new TagEventHandler(rfid_TagLost);
        rfid1.open();

        Text = cc.Title() + " ( Login )";
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        groupBox2.Visible = true;
    }

    public void RFIDLogin()
    {

        if (textBox4.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(cc.connectDB());
            con.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("delete from log", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand("select * from Login where RFID='" + textBox4.Text + "'", con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCeDataReader c = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (c.Read() == true)
            {
                SqlCeCommand cmd2 = new SqlCeCommand("select typeid from Login where RFID='" + textBox4.Text + "'", con);
                Int32 count = (Int32)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    SqlCeCommand cmd3 = new SqlCeCommand("insert into log values ('" + 1 + "')", con);
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Menu shw = new Menu();
                    shw.Show();
                    textBox4.Enabled = false;
                    txtTag.Enabled = false;
                    this.Hide();
                    sp.SpeakAsync("Welcome To Canvey Island GYM");

                }
                else
                    if (count == 2)
                    {
                        SqlCeCommand cmd3 = new SqlCeCommand("insert into log values ('" + 2 + "')", con);
                        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Menu shw = new Menu();
                        shw.Show();
                        textBox4.Enabled = false;
                        txtTag.Enabled = false;
                        this.Hide();
                        sp.SpeakAsync("Welcome To Canvey Island GYM");
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
                sp.SpeakAsync("Login Failed");
            }

        }
    }

    public void ent()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(cc.connectDB());
            con.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("delete from log", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand("select * from Login where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCeDataReader c = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (c.Read() == true)
            {
                SqlCeCommand cmd2 = new SqlCeCommand("select typeid from Login where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
                Int32 count = (Int32)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    SqlCeCommand cmd3 = new SqlCeCommand("insert into log values ('" + 1 + "')", con);
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                    if (count == 2)
                    {
                        SqlCeCommand cmd3 = new SqlCeCommand("insert into log values ('" + 2 + "')", con);
                        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                sp.SpeakAsync("Welcome To Canvey Island GYM");
                Menu shw = new Menu();
                shw.Show();
                textBox4.Enabled = false;
                this.Hide();

            }
            else
            {
                sp.SpeakAsync("Login Failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ent();
    }

    //private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    //    {
    //        ent();
    //    }
    //}

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        groupBox2.Visible = true;   
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox2.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RFIDLogin();
        rfid1.close();
    }


    void rfid_Tag(object sender, TagEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Text = e.Tag;
        txtTag.Text = e.Tag;
        lastRFIDTag = txtTag.Text;
        rfid1.LED = true;       // light on
    }

    void rfid_TagLost(object sender, TagEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTag.Text = "";
        rfid1.LED = false;      // light off
        //write held Tag ID to listview
        lbPrevRFIDTags.Items.Insert(0,
            string.Format("Tag: {0} - {1}", ++TagCtr, lastRFIDTag));
    }

    void rfid_Detach(object sender, DetachEventArgs e)
    {
        lblAttached.Text = "Not Attached";
    }

    void rfid_Attach(object sender, AttachEventArgs e)
    {
        Phidgets.RFID phid = (Phidgets.RFID)sender;
        lblAttached.Text = "Attached: " + phid.Name;
        lblSerial.Text = " Serial: " + phid.SerialNumber;
        lblVersion.Text = " Version: " + phid.Version;
    }

    private void cboxAntenna_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rfid1.Antenna = cboxAntenna.Checked;
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: this.Hide(); funtion only hide login form and open main form, however still active in backend the login form, where RFID code is, and still accessable to RFID key

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this this RFID device how ever with mine when the reader is singulating it continues to pick up the same tag over and over in the tagEventHandler. All i did was create a

```
bool scantag = true;
```

Then control your RFID method with it when you want it to pick up tags

```
void rfid_Tag(object sender, TagEventArgs e)
{

if(scantag == true)
{        

scantag = false;
textBox4.Text = e.Tag;
txtTag.Text = e.Tag;
lastRFIDTag = txtTag.Text;
rfid1.LED = true;       // light on


}

//wait for user to remove tag
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

// enable the handler again
scantag = true;

}
```